# Generate page url rather than data id with JSON in Umbraco

Tags: json, umbraco, umbraco7

(Please bare in mind that I am new to Umbraco and JSON!)

In Umbraco, I'm looking to use JSON (alongside HTML and CSS) to turn grid cells into buttons. So far I've accomplished this using the below code (generated from an amalgamation of different tutorials/guides), but this is generating urls which end with the numerical data-id of the page. E.g. www.mywebsite.com/0000/. This works as a link and goes to the correct place, but I'd much rather it generated a URL with the correct name? I.e. something more like www.mywebsite.com/page-name/.

How can this be done?

```
{
"label": "destination",
"description": "Choose destination",
"view": "treepicker",
"key": "class=\"button\"><a class=\"buttonLink\" href",
"applyTo": "cell"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Umbraco, then you can easily get the URL or URlName of the page you are on.

IPublishedContent has all these properties and you can inherit this interface to your class to access these.

Thanks